# Convergence of the sequence $\frac{\sqrt 2}{(n-\sqrt n )^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits

I thought I can say  $n \geq (n-\sqrt n ) \geq \frac{n}{2} $ and also $n^2 \geq (n-\sqrt n )^2 \geq (\frac{n}{2})^2 $

As a result of that $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt 2}{n^2} = 0$  and $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt 2}{\frac{n}{2}^2} = 0$

I can say that applies:

$\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt 2}{n^2} \geq \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt 2}{(n-\sqrt n )^2} \geq \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt 2}{\frac{n}{2}^2}$

Which follows that $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt 2}{(n-\sqrt n )^2}  = 0$

Is that a correct proof?

Comment: Inequality $n-\sqrt{n}\geq n/2$ doesn't hold for all $n$, and we have $\sqrt{2}/n^2\leq\sqrt{2}/(n-\sqrt{n})^2\leq \sqrt{2}/(n/2)^2$ (you have inequalities of limits other way around). Otherwise, the approach is correct.

Comment: Does it have to be that elaborate? After all, you are dividing a constant by a "polynomial" term that has a degree greater than 1

Comment: Well @imranfat my prof said we should elaborate a little bit yeah, but you're right this is trivial.

Comment: @Wojowu so I'll say it holds for all $n >$ than a specific $x$?

Comment: I see, observe that $n<n^2-2n*\sqrt{n}+n<n^2+n$ for large $n$ and use squeeze theorem